# Python, converting *.dcm files to *.png (dicom)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, pydicom

I am trying to convert *.dcm file to *.jpg file.
while I do that
I am using this code :

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pydicom
from PIL import Image


def get_names_of_imgs_inside_folder(directory):

    names = []

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
            if ext in [".dcm"]:
                names.append(filename)

    return names

def convert(directory):
    im = pydicom.dcmread('Database/'+directory)
    im = im.pixel_array.astype(float)

    rescaled_image = (np.maximum(im,0)/im.max())*255 # float pixels
    final_image = np.uint8(rescaled_image) # integers pixels

    final_image = Image.fromarray(final_image)
    return final_image

names = get_names_of_imgs_inside_folder('Database')

for name in names:
    image = convert(name)
    image.save(name+'.jpg')
```

but at line 20 I get this error :

> File is missing DICOM File Meta Information header or the 'DICM'
> prefix  is missing from the header. Use force=True to force reading.

How can I fix this problem .Can anybody help me please

Comment: Are you sure these are valid DICOM files? If yes, have you tried to do what the error message suggests?

Comment: yes I sure and I have tried. after try I have take this message 

"AttributeError: 'FileMetaDataset' object has no attribute 'TransferSyntaxUID'"

Comment: This does look like invalid DICOM data. Does that happen with every DICOM file?

Comment: you can check, if the meta data header is missing with `dicom = pydicom.read_file(dicom_img)` and `print(dicom)`